# Solr Nested (child) entities

Tags: database, indexing, solr, nodes, entities

In my dataConfig I followed this example. 
Solr version: 6.0.0

```
 <dataConfig> 
<dataSource driver="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" url="jdbc:hsqldb:/temp/example/ex" user="sa" /> 
<document name="products"> 
<entity name="item" query="select * from item"> 
<field column="ID" name="id" /> 
<field column="NAME" name="name" /> 
<field column="MANU" name="manu" /> 
<field column="WEIGHT" name="weight" /> 
<field column="PRICE" name="price" /> 
<field column="POPULARITY" name="popularity" /> 
<field column="INSTOCK" name="inStock" /> 
<field column="INCLUDES" name="includes" />

<entity name="feature" query="select description from feature where item_id='${item.ID}'"> 
<field name="features" column="description" /> 
</entity> 
<entity name="item_category" query="select CATEGORY_ID from item_category where item_id='${item.ID}'"> 
<entity name="category" query="select description from category where id = '${item_category.CATEGORY_ID}'"> 
<field column="description" name="cat" /> 
</entity> 
</entity> 
</entity> 
</document> 
</dataConfig>
```

But after data import I can't get the child nodes. 
I also tried with dynamic fields and i get the same result. 
Is there something that has to be done before importing data to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the PK attribute to your item entity:

```
<entity name="item" pk="ID" query="select * from item">
```

This should make it available to its children.